# After compiling from Dart to Javascript, document.querySelector can't find <body>

Tags: javascript, dart, document, dart2js

I'm getting `null` when trying to find `<body>` element with `querySelector()` on `document` object after compiling to javascript. Here's the Dart code:

```dart
void main() {
  print(document.querySelector('body')); // => null
}
```

This also produces a range error:

```dart
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] // => Range error, obviously the List is empty
```

The dart code works just fine in Dartium though.

Comment: I should also add there's definitely a `<body>` element in the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. I included the script in the `<head>` section, and should've done it after all the contents inside `<body>`.

Comment: one should use `defer` for scripts that need to wait until the document is parsed. Unfortunately, `pub build` does not transform deferred dart scripts. Things that make me go hmm

Answer (score 1):

Weird, but you don't need `querySelector()` for the `body` element.
Just use `document.body`

Comment: Still no luck, `document.body` prints `null`